# How to center the caption while I am using \scalebox from pgf package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, captions

I am using the [package pgf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) to scale a .pgf image however I can't understand how to scale the image to exactely the text width. So the caption seems uncenterd because it is centerd referred to the text center and not refered to the image center.

[image]

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} 
    \centering
    \scalebox{0.5}{\input{test.pgf}}   
    \caption{Can you center me? Can you center me?Can you center me?}   
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

#### Is there a way to scale the image to exactly the text width while I am using this package? Or there is a way to center the caption referring to the image center instead of the text center?

A simple pgf file for testing is could be this:

```
\begingroup%
\makeatletter%
\begin{pgfpicture}%
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{12.162500in}{9.737500in}}%
\pgfusepath{use as bounding box, clip}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.300000,0.300000,0.300000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetfillopacity{0.500000}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.003750pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.300000,0.300000,0.300000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.500000}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.242710in}{0.201968in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{11.948671in}{0.201968in}}%
\pgfpathquadraticcurveto{\pgfqpoint{11.976437in}{0.201968in}}{\pgfqpoint{11.976437in}{0.229735in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{11.976437in}{0.844102in}}%
\pgfpathquadraticcurveto{\pgfqpoint{11.976437in}{0.871868in}}{\pgfqpoint{11.948671in}{0.871868in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.242710in}{0.871868in}}%
\pgfpathquadraticcurveto{\pgfqpoint{0.214944in}{0.871868in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.214944in}{0.844102in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.214944in}{0.229735in}}%
\pgfpathquadraticcurveto{\pgfqpoint{0.214944in}{0.201968in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.242710in}{0.201968in}}%
\pgfpathclose%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfpicture}%
\makeatother%
\endgroup%
```

Comment: Use `\fbox{\scalebox{0.4}{\input{test.pgf}}}` to make the image size visible. I suppose it has some whitespace around or uses the whole line

Comment: Also I'd recommend creating all figures in their natural size so no scaling is needed. Then fontsizes and line width will be consistent through out the doc.

Comment: @GM without more information about document class and the contents of `test.pgf` there is not much we can do. How is the centering if you replace the `\scalebox` line by `\rule{3cm}{3cm}`? Just to rule out the class making interesting choices

Comment: @daleif yes that would be perfect unfortunately is not always possible. Some times you need to adapt already made figure and this is the case.

Comment: Still, this looks unprofessional.

Comment: @GM: Sure, `\fbox` does nothing else as to show the real width. Try `\makebox[\linewidth]{\scalebox{...}}`

Comment: \centering doesn't center the caption normally. Your question doesn't make sense at it is. Show a complete example.

Comment: @daleif thanks for your precious help! I understood that the problem arise from the fact the the caption is centered relative to the text center I have edit the question with a more detailed MWE.

Comment: @GM this is not a concrete example, we still need information about which document class you are using as it may incluence hos captions etc behaves. Basically provide a **minimal** example we can copy and test without having to add anything to it. This MWE is basically the currency here, you pay the MWE we provide help.

Comment: @daleif ok sorry! I did not think was so necessary I think is more a theory question however I edit the question make a basic  latex article class file and copy and paste the pgf code to a empty test.pgf file and keep it in the same directory.

Comment: @GM you'd be surprised how many questions end up with _but this does not work in my real doc using class xxx_, it is basically to avoid wasting time. Some classes will e.g. force captions to be left aligned.

Comment: BTW: is this PGF code autogenerated? If not, why so low level? wouldn't it be easier to draw in tikz (which sits on top of pgf). The scaled image as it sits now, is wider than the test width, so alignment looks odd. Also the bounding box on that PGF image is much larger than the drawn rectangle.

Comment: @daleif yes it is. I can't show the image I am publishing it, I don't think is relevant to scope of this question however.

Comment: `\scalebox` is defined by the `graphics` package, not the `pgf` package. If you want to scale anything to a fixed width then you should use `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{..}` not `\scalebox` but then `\centering` will have  no effect as the image is full width and the caption positions itself.

Comment: You can either size the graphics to \textwidth with resizebox as suggested by David, or let is stick out left and right with `\makebox[\textwidth]{\scalebox{0.5}{...}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can scale something to the text width with `\resizebox`. Or if your image is larger than the text width you can let stick it out of both margins with `\makebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\makebox[\textwidth]{\scalebox{1.8}{\rule{10cm}{1cm}}}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{{\rule{10cm}{1cm}}}
\caption{Can you center me? Can you center me?Can you center me?}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`\scalebox` is defined by `graphics` not by `pgf`.

If you want an object to be `\textwidth` wide then

```
  \scalebox{0.5}{...}
```

will not work unless the original was exactly twice textwidth originally.

Use

```
   \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{...}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used `\leftskip` instead of `\centering` Hope the below answer help to you:

```
\begin{figure}
\leftskip-4pt
    \scalebox{0.4}{\input{test.pgf}}
    \caption{Can you center me? Can you center me?Can you center me?}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: It is best never to set `\leftskip` directly in latex it is a tex primitive and if you set it directly you break the required correspondences between the the left and right skips, `\linewidth` and `\textwidth`